# $db->insertid() return 0 event when no error in $db->execute()

Tags: php, joomla4

I am developing an extension in Joomla 4.

I need to insert a record, so I did this:

```
        $columns = array('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'cellular', 'checked_out_time');
        $values = array($db->quoteName($nombre), $db->quoteName($apellido), $db->quoteName($email), $db->quoteName($celular), $db->quoteName($fecha->toSQL()));
        
        $saveQuery
                ->insert($db->quoteName('#__compra_tickets_apoderado'))
                ->columns($db->quoteName($columns))
                ->values(implode(',', $values));
        
        $db->setQuery($query);
        if (false !== ($result = $db->execute())) {
            echo $db->insertid();
        } else {
            echo 0;
        }
```

Even when `execute` method returns `true`, no record is inserted and `$db->insertid()` return 0.

Any hint, please?

Comment: The code you've posted is incomplete: `$query` is not defined in the snippet

Comment: It doesn't matter. It was a silly thing. I realized about it according to the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you use `$saveQuery` for building the query, but then you pass `$query` to `setQuery()` which is most likely different query you crafted earlier. So that's why you do not get any warning about using unassigned variable (because it exists), and because its content is a valid query, the `execute()` technically works, but "this is not the query you are looking for"®. And as since that old query is non-`INSERT` (my guess, just `SELECT` so you do not mess with your data with that double query execution), there's nothing inserted to get the `insertid()` of.

Side note: `quoteName()` is used to escape database identifiers, such as column names, not values as you did. For inserting values, you should use `quote()` instead.

Comment: Thanks!  Problem solved. I was really careless.